# Managing multiple .Net-Frameworks on a webserver

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-1.1, multiple-versions

So I'm in charge to deploy my project on the productive server where some other ASP.NET-Websites are also set up.

The problem now is that I wrote my whole project under .NET 3.5 but on the webserver the current installation is .NET 1.1 as some of the other projects require them (don't ask me why, I can't figure it out either but my PM says so...) and thus I'm not allowed installing 3.5 for now but I'm not at all in the mood of rewriting my project on 1.1.

Now; is it possible (and if yes, how) to manage multiple installations of .NET, so sort of assigning the projects which version to use? (Say: Project X use .NET 1.1, Project Y use 3.5) or are there possible conflicts that could crash one or another of the projects when I install 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different .NET framework versions can be assigned per virtual directory in IIS (provided that these two virtual directories are assigned to **different** application pools). So if you have two virtual directories in your web server say `App1` and `App2` you can assign `App1` to use .NET 1.1 and `App2` to use .NET 3.5 or more precisely ASP.NET 2.0. For this to work you need to install .NET 3.5 on the server.

[image]

Comment: Okay, that's good news, but... Where can I assign these? Sorry if that's a stupid question but I don't find anything on that topic in the help or documentation of the server. I'm completely new to that, isn't there sort of a tutorial on that?!

Comment: Oops, didn't get a notice you changed your post. Thanks a lot, I'm going to try that.

Comment: Well, I guess I found that window there, But the only tabs I don't have that ASP.NET-Tab, after Custom Errors the next tab is "Server Extensions 2002" (own translation). Am I in a wrong window now?!

Comment: Well, I guess this tab will become available when you install multiple versions of the framework. If you have only 1.1 installed on the machine this tab is useless. Once you install .NET 3.5 it will register within IIS (using `aspnet_regiis -ir`) and you can use it.

Comment: Okay, so I have to convince my PM that it's possible but only after it has been installed... that could be interesting. Thank you ;-)

Comment: Show him on a test server or a VPC... 
I've done this on a number of servers, in test and production. No problem at all. Running 1.1, 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0 apps side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works, see the screenshot by Darin. Note, though, that .net 1.1 and .net 2 CLR (= 2.0, 3.0, 3.5) applications need to run in different application pools (you will receive an error when accessing a .net X web application which runs in the same pool as an already running .net Y web application).

PS: I've found a [tutorial on setting up different app pools for side-by-side running of asp.net 1.1 and 2.0](http://www.gafvert.info/iis/article/install_asp_net_20_side_by_side.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

You can have Apps running .Net 1.1, Apps Running .Net 2 CLR (2.0, 3.0, 3.5) and also Apps running .Net 4.0