# Microsoft Server 2003 with .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net-3.5, windows-server-2003

As a follow-up question [on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713948/managing-multiple-net-frameworks-on-a-webserver);

The server running is a Microsoft Server 2003. Are there any possible (bad) outcomes when trying to install .NET 3.5 on such a server, that only has 1.1 installed and running in order to split up web-applications based on 1.1 and 3.5?

Comment: This really sounds like a serverfault.com question.

Comment: Oh, yeah... sorry I forgot the quantity of communites that are associated here :) Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, the .net 3.5 run time environment can run along with the 1.1 with no problem. All you have to do is make sure that the 1.1 applications and the 3.5 applications are in different application pools in IIS.

Comment: Do I still need to install 2.0 SP1 as well? I read 3.5 is based on that one?

Comment: Yes, the .net 3.5 runs on the 2.0 run time environment.

Comment: *Sigh*, would have been to easy for M$ do get every version running for it's own... Thanks for your help.

Comment: You just have to think of 3.5 as really 2.0+

Comment: So why don't they just call it 2.5 and let that run on it's own. I will never understand that company^^